# Bookdown - specify MathJax URL?

Tags: r, r-markdown, mathjax, bookdown

When using Bookdown, is it possible to specify a custom URL for MathJax? The version served by RStudio is out of date, and I would like to use the most up to date version.

I have tried the following:

_output.yml:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  mathjax: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"
```

index.Rmd:

```
--- 
title: "Untitled"
author: "An author"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
---

$$E=mc^2$$
```

However, if I right click on the MathJax equation in the browser it shows the version as 2.7.2, not the intended version 3.0.5. Checking the html shows it is loading MathJax from `mathjax.rstudio.com/latest`, not the specified url.

Interestingly, in plain RMarkdown the following does correctly load MathJax 3.

Untitled.Rmd:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "An author"
date: "15/07/2020"
output: 
  html_document: 
        mathjax: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"
        keep_md: yes
---

$$E = mc^2$$
```

(Edit: raised [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/915))